# How to add extension in firefox driver in Java using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, firefox-headless

How to add extension in firefox driver in selenium in Java

Have tried below possibilities.

**1st tried Solution**

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File("/usr/local/bin/foxyproxy_standard-6.6.2-an+fx.xpi"));
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1");
firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

It is not giving any error but it is starting without any extension.

Used dependancy

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**2nd tried Solution**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File("/usr/local/bin/foxyproxy_standard-6.6.2-an+fx.xpi"));
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1");
WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

It is also not giving any error but it is starting without any extension.

Used dependancy

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**3rd tried Solution**

Created manually profile from firefox.
 1. Open default firefox
 2. about:prfiles
 3. Created new profile as 'TestProfile'
 4. Launch profile in new browser
 5. Add some add ons
 6. Close browser
 7. And then execute below code.

```
    ProfilesIni profilesIni = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    FirefoxProfile profile = profilesIni.getProfile("TestProfile");
    firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
    WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

This is also not working

I have tried with chrome driver also it is working fine but chromedriver does not have extension support in headless mode so need to use firefox webdriver.

**I have tried all solution are given already but none of them is working**

So please guid me what to do.

Comment: Can you update the question with all of your code trials and associated errors?

Comment: I have added all solutions now can look once @DebanjanB

Comment: Try with FF68,selenium-java 4.0.0-alpha-2 and v0.24.0 .Tried on windows machine . Extension loaded properly without any issue.  `
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.addExtension(new File("foxyproxy_basic-5.5-an+fx.xpi"));
            options.setProfile(profile); `

Comment: Thanks @RahulL this is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with FF68,selenium-java 4.0.0-alpha-2 and v0.24.0 . Tested on Windows machine.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.addExtension(new File("foxyproxy_basic-5.5-an+fx.xpi"));

options.setProfile(profile);
```

Comment: This only works in 4.0.0 alpha version? I am trying it for 3.141.59 but it doesn't work

Comment: Checked with Selenium-java 3.141.59 ,geckodriver 0.26.0 (e9783a644016 2019-10-10 13:38 +0000) + FF72 . Its working fine.

Comment: uhh really?, I can't really add the extension. Its totally same code.

Comment: Can you please add more information about how you create the driver? I mean the whole code, if possible

Comment: `FirefoxOptions optionsFF = new FirefoxOptions();
            
             FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
             profile.addExtension(new File("foxyproxy_basic-5.5-an+fx.xpi"));
             optionsFF.setProfile(profile);
             
             optionsFF.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);//for logs
             driver = new FirefoxDriver(optionsFF); `

Comment: I did it, the problem was when you are trying to install your own extension and if you forgot to add application and minimum browser version tags, it won't work...

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli What is the syntax for the application and minimum browser tags? I trying to use the former code but I didn't manage to load an extension in Firefox (I'm using WebDriver 4.0.0-beta-4)

Comment: @BoniGarcía "applications": {
      "gecko": {
    "id": "ahmet.besli@hotmail.com0",

        "strict_min_version": "52.0"
     }
  },

Comment: @BoniGarcía https://easyupload.io/gz16ap   here is a old example of mine, you can check, I was just using it to block google's urls